# Binary to Decimal Conversion in Java (breaking out of the loop)

Tags: java, javafx

My conversion code is working fine, however I can't seem to restrict the user from inputting numbers other than 0 and 1. I've managed to deal with it to a certain extent: the program recognizes the number (for example 2), but it continues converting numbers that come after it simply ignoring the 2 itself and moving on. If I enter 2011, it's going to convert it to 3 in decimal (011 = 3), instead of breaking completely. I'm assuming it has something to do with the first condition, but I don't know how to fix it, so any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm working in JavaFX, hence the usage of the textfield (t3).

```
int decimal = 0;
int power = 0;
int bin = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());

while (bin != 0) {
  int temp = bin%10;
  if(temp > 1) {
  break;
  } else {
      bin = bin / 10;
      decimal += temp * Math.pow(2, power);
      power++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `int bin = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText(), 2);`

Comment: You could use an if statement that sees if bin contains a number other than 0 or 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just break out of look if number is greater than 1, throw NumberFormatException.

```
int decimal = 0;
int power = 0;
int bin = Integer.parseInt("11");

while (bin != 0) {
  int temp = bin%10;
  if(temp > 1) {
  throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid input"); //throw exception if input contains number greater than 0
  } else {
      bin = bin / 10;
      decimal += temp * Math.pow(2, power);
      power++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the radix in the parseInt call

```
int bin = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText(), 2);
```

which will parse a binary number and throw a `NumberFormatException` on illegal input.

Comment: i tried doing that but then the rest of my code worked in a funny way, so the other answer is more appropriate for me this time. thank you for your help, i'll keep this in mind for the next time!

Comment: In which way is the rest of your code working funny? If you had listened to Neil or Elliot you could just delete that code because it is not needed anymore and so I doubt that it could then still work funny.